# Must have add-ons

Tags: add-on, ee4, addons

I know this is a peer project related question but what are your must have add-ons? Which add-ons are you using in all your project especially for EE4.X

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not fixed that some addons you must have to develop EE website. But if you want then below are the addons of EE which usually I used.

- [BBD Chopper](https://github.com/BlackBeltDesigns/bbd_chopper.ee_addon) (Chopper takes your entry's content and whittles it down to a more manageable size. It strips the HTML and limits the excerpts by character count, word count or cutoff marker.)
- [CE Image](https://docs.causingeffect.com/expressionengine/ce-image/index.html) (CE Image is an image manipulation tool for use in your ExpressionEngine templates.)
- [Deeploy Helper](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/deeploy-helper) (Manage paths and URLs more easily with Deeploy Helper.)
- [Freeform Pro](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs) (Freeform is the most powerful form building add-on for ExpressionEngine. It gives you full control to create simple or complex multi-page forms, as well as connect your forms to many popular API integrations.)
- [Low Search](https://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) (Low Search is used to search any content on your website. To integrate Global Site Search or specific search functionality.)
- [SEO Lite](http://wedoaddons.com/seo-lite) (SEO Lite is the easiest way to make sure the title-tag is output on all pages on your site: one global embed / snippet and you're done. SEO Lite is a very lightweight module which will add a SEO tab to your publish page.)
- [Wygwam](https://eeharbor.com/wygwam/documentation) (Wygwam’s WYSIWYG editor is based on the powerful and accessible CKEditor 4, which we’ve custom-tuned to work exceptionally well with ExpressionEngine.)

These are the most usable addons of EE. I think all EE developers are using these addons. Also these are very famous addons in EE's world.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any "must have" addons, and have built a fair few EE sites that use no 3rd party addons at all.

That said I use 3rd party addons where native EE functionality either can't do what I need it to do, or they make things easier for site owners.

If I do use 3rd party addons there are a few that regularly crop up:

Low Variables - great for managing miscellaneous content like phone numbers, micro copy, social media URL's etc. It also works well for front end settings like switching things on/off!

WYGWAM - for when you need an enhanced WYSIWYG editor, the best bit is that you can control formatting buttons per custom field.

Freeform - if you need to store form submissions, you can use Channel Form to store submissions but that can overwhelm your entries listings.

Answer (score 0):

I echo earlier comments about add-ons not being required to build an EE4 site, but there are some add-ons that I think are worth including in any base build.  They are (alphabetically ordered):

- [Caddis Math](https://github.com/caddis/math) - to do simple mathematical operations within templates
- [Mo'Variables](https://github.com/rsanchez/mo_variables) - a useful collection of additional system / global variables
- [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash) - Complex to use, but handy mechanism for temporary storage within / across templates (and some other things) - but increasingly becoming less necessary as EE4 builds in similar features
- [Caddis Streeng](https://github.com/caddis/streeng) - Handy string manipulations - need perhaps being replaced by EE4 variable modifiers, but still does many things that variable modifiers cannot :)
- [URL Helper](https://github.com/litzinger/URL-Helper) - a Swiss army knife of utilities to access and manipulate URL slugs

There are some other add-ons that are exceptional and often are useful, but not always required (and / or other ways of doing these things exist):

- [CE Image](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/) - Still works under EE4 but long in need of an update or replacement; provides ability to perform customised manipulation of images within templates.
- [GWCode Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation) or [Category Construct](https://buzzingpixel.com/ee-add-ons/category-construct) - Handy tools to work with category information within templates (EE4 compatible version of GW Categories can be found via second posting [here](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/gwcode-categories/viewthread/15375))
- [Low Reorder](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-reorder/docs) - Allows for creation of dynamic lists (e.g. based on channels, categories, search terms etc.) that then can be re-ordered arbitrarily - surprisingly useful
- [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs) - Provides fine-grain access / control of search within EE

Finally, although not strictly necessary, you might also want to consider adding a more complete Rich Text Editor than ships with EE4, I use [Wyvern](https://docs.reinos.nl/wyvern/).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

EE4 (presumably also EE5) is so well-packed, out of the box I don't need anything.

However, if using forms, FreeForm Pro is fantastic. I'd happily shell out the $ for this if I'm doing anything more than, say, a basic contact form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your advice/comments..
Actually, i often use these Addons

- Low variables for multilingual site and miscellaneous content.
- Channel Images for image manipulation (maybe i could use EE4 for that but i need different kind of cropping..)
- Antenna for video implementation
- DataGrab to import data from RSS and/or custom json file i generate from other website)
- WYGWAM .
- PDF Press for few website..
- FreeFrom when i need file upload
- Snaptcha to avoid too many spam..
- Expresso Store when i need complex ecommerce solution

That's a lot, i know and sometime i wish i could do it without any Addons because when it's time to Upgrade it can be ?%@%$&@..